# Do I need to submit my IOS app if I only need the link valid

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

It's the first time I submit a app to apple. I have a app need to start from click an email link, I'm trying deep linking and I want to test it now, so I need a link from apple, I get that link from my ITunes Connect, now my APP is in 1.0 prepare to submit. but when I click the link it cannot find in itunes, is it means I have to submit app to apple now, its not finish so I afraid apple will reject it. or there's some other way to do it? Thank you!

Comment: when you  app will approve and will show on ituns than next version you can give the previous version appiTunes link

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After pass apple's review, I found out the link I need is not a itunes link. itunes link is for user did not installed my App. I was need open my App from another link in email. 
what i need to do is add a url scheme in plist. the following link is best guide for what should do:
[link](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html)

and add conference to server and ios part as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15983797/can-a-uiwebview-interact-communicate-with-the-app)
, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14048159/redirect-to-application-if-installed-otherwise-to-appstore).

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you will get iTunes link once your app will be approved. So next time (or next version), you can use the previous version link to test redirection.

At the moment, you can do like upload your adhoc build to other site like Fabric (https://fabric.io) or Diawi (https://diawi.com/) and pass that build link to your email and check that it is opening the application build.

Hope it helps to check your deep-link development.

Comment: get it , Thanks!